# Buildbot svn error when checking local copy

Tags: svn, buildbot

Trying to do an incremental checkout using Buildbot and SVN but Buildbot keeps removing the entire tree first. I believe it's because of the code 2 errors in the log but I can't find any information on how to resolve them:

```
stat: No such file or directory: **/home/mtrew/Documents/svn/card/branches/galrel1_13/.buildbot-patched
program finished with exit code 2
stat: No such file or directory: /home/mtrew/Documents/svn/card/branches/galrel1_13/.svn
program finished with exit code 2**
rm -rf /home/mtrew/Documents/svn/card/branches/galrel1_13
in dir /home/mtrew/Documents/buildbot/slave/galbuild (timeout 1200 secs)
watching logfiles {}
argv: ['rm', '-rf', '/home/mtrew/Documents/svn/card/branches/galrel1_13']
```

The step in the cfg file that sets up the checkout is:

```
f_galbuild.addStep(steps.SVN(mode='incremental',
            method='fresh',
            repourl='http://titan/svn/sw/trunk/card/branches/galrel1_13',
            username = "XXXXX",
            password = "XXXXX",
            workdir = "/home/mtrew/Documents/svn/card/branches/galrel1_13"))
```

Answer (score 0):

From  [Buildbot 0.8.10's Build Steps Documentation](http://docs.buildbot.net/0.8.10/manual/cfg-buildsteps.html#svn):

```
SVN's incremental mode does not require a method.
```

So perhaps there's some sort of conflict happening because you've set a mode of incremental but with methods meant for full?